# regex that handles a decimal point if it exists

Tags: php, regex

I am using a php regular expression to try and solve an advanced text search query in mysql. The query needs to group smaller things to make them work properly. Currently I can handle things like "foo 7S" and group them together if I see the word "foo".

Currently, my regex looks as such

```
/(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b/i
```

However, if I am trying to search for something specific like "foo 7.10", then the ".10" is split out instead of being combined. My current regular expression is

```
/(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\b/i
```

This works for "foo 7.10" but doesn't match anything for "foo 7" or "foo 7S". Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the group that captures the decimal part optional:

```
(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?\b
                                                  ^
```

https://regex101.com/r/QBFeuP/1

Note that since you're using the `i` flag, the regex is case-insensitive, so there's no need to use `a-zA-z` - those can be reduced to just `a-z`:

```
(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z0-9]+)?\b
```

and if there is no chance of underscores being there, you can use `\w` instead:

```
(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+(\w+)(\.\w+)?\b
```

in which case the final `\b` is unnecessary, because both of the `\w+`s are *greedy* and will match as many characters as they can, which implies that the following position will *necessarily* be a word boundary.

You also might consider putting a word boundary at the very beginning, if it would be helpful:

```
\b(foo|bar|baz faz)\s+(\w+)(\.\w+)?
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was missing. I had tried the ? before the third capture, but obviously that wasn't working either.